# How am I protected by a VPN when the traffic first has to flow unprotected from my laptop to the VPN server itself?

Tags: vpn

I was reading about VPNs and I understand that a VPN server can protect my traffic in a way that will prevent the end-server from knowing my original location, plus there are additional encryptions.
But how can a VPN server protect me from my ISP when the request from my laptop has to go first through my home router, then through the network of my ISP and finally reach the VPN server which will then encrypt the traffic and do its job.
So the traffic between my laptop and the VPN server is still unprotected.